# How to cache a fragment view

Tags: android, caching, view, fragment

I'd like to cache a fragment view. My Activity has swipeable tabs and each tab calls a different fragment. But when i swipe between tabs the transition seems a quite slow because of the destruction of the fragment view, that is rebuilded during the swipe operation. Does anyone know how can i cache the view of each fragment to prevent this issue?
I work with library support v4 and api 14

I tried to implement a constructor for the fragments, called by the activity container of the fragments: i call the constructor, the fragments are created as variable of the activity class and then, whenever a fragment has to show itself, the activity class returns the fragment object i created before, but this doesn't improve my application a lot because the view of the fragment is destroyed anyway

Comment: have you tried caching the view in fragment itself and on the onCreateView you return the cached fragment? Or the view is always destroyed?

Comment: Do you use `ViewPager` for your "swipeable tabs"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because internally by default the pager loads a maximum of 3 pages (fragments) at the time:
the one displaying, previous and next so if you have 5 fragments this will happen while you move from first to last: (where x is a loaded fragment)

xx000
->
xxx00
->
0xxx0
->
00xxx
->
000xx

Try using

```
myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ITEMS_COUNT-1);
```

This will tell the pager to keep all of them in memory and not destroy/create with every swipe (keep a close look on the memory management)

Comment: Won't this call `onCreateView` of a tab fragment?
(Where the fragment layout view is loaded)

Comment: @StarDust yes, this will call onCreateView for all the fragments at the same time at the beginning.It's tricky, you can run out of memory or simply will get a black screen or block because of the fragment loading process. This solution is nice if you have to load 4 or 5 light fragments but I wouldn't do it for 10 heavy-loading fragments. You can set the offscreenPageLimit to any number lower than your fragments count, for example if you have 10 pages and set the limit to 4 and you are in the 6th screen, it will load 2 extra in both directions like this 000xx **x** xx00 (best solution I think)