# Is caching Fragment a good practice?

Tags: android

There's one `Activity`, one Side menu and many `Fragment`s. when I selected menus in side menu, a specific `Fragment` added into activity and a previous one is removed. In this application, do I have to cache `Fragment` object? or just recreate new `Fragment` every time I selected menu? which one is better?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291739/how-to-cache-a-fragment-view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 do I have to cache Fragment object?
```

Remember that if you cached a Fragment with multiple view within it, it can cost you memory which can lead to `OutOfMemoryException` that your heap is full and you are allocating memory to another fragment.

```
or just recreate new Fragment every time I selected menu? which one is better?
```

If your fragment does not have a lot of View on it then i would cache only 1 or 2 fragment from each side.

Lets say you have 5 fragments ( 1 - 2 - **3** - 4 - 5) and you are currently at the `3rd fragment` I would only cache the **2nd** and **4th** fragment **but** not the `1st and 5th fragment`, **but** if I changed fragment to **4th** then I would cached `3rd and 5th fragment` and **remove** the cached **2nd** fragment. Now if you do this then youll save time rendering it again to the screen. But always remember it can cost you memory.

If you want to a memory wise application specially for device with lower heap size then recreate the fragment each time you select a menu.